# How does resizing of images work with lighttpd?

Tags: 7, media

I switched the Webserver from Apache to Lighttpd. Since then, resizing images according to the defined sytles (/admin/config/media/image-styles) does not work anymore.

Anybody knows what may be missing?

**Edit:** Added excerpt from phpinfo():

*gd*

```
GD Support: enabled
GD Version: 2.0
FreeType Support: enabled
FreeType Linkage: with freetype
FreeType Version: 2.4.8
T1Lib Support: enabled
GIF Read Support: enabled
GIF Create Support: enabled
JPEG Support: enabled
libJPEG Version: unknown
PNG Support:    enabled
libPNG Version: 1.2.46
WBMP Support: enabled
```

*imagick*

```
imagick module: enabled
imagick module version: 3.1.0RC1
imagick classes: Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator
ImageMagick version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2012-08-17 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date: 2012-08-17
ImageMagick number of supported formats: 206
ImageMagick supported formats: [.....Many!!]
```

Comment: Do you have a PHP image processing library installed? gd and imagemagick are supported as standard. You should be able to see at /admin/reports/status or in phpinfo

Comment: GD as well as imagemagick is installed, and shown as available in phpinfo()

Comment: "does not work" is most popular, and most useless statement in IT. What exactly happens when you try? What appears in server's error.log and Drupal's watchdog?

Comment: Last but not least, how do you generate image tags? Maybe it's simply lack of access token? What is HTTP response?

Comment: „Does not work“ means that the other images styles are not available on the file system, but referenced in the article (tumbnail, medium and large). I do not use image tags. Drupal just tells me that the article has been added ord modified, There are no error.log outputs when the issue occurs.

Comment: is clean urls running?

Comment: In order for image styles to be generated, requests for the URLs in question have to be passed to Drupal when the file does not already exist. The default .htaccess file for Drupal includes a rule which does this. My suspicion would be your current Lighttpd configuration does not.

Comment: @AlirezaTabatabaeian Clean URLs is activated and working

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong You mean this one?  
 
    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico  
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`

Comment: Yes. Have you checked that a request for a file that is not present goes to Drupal?

Comment: Have you checked the the file and folder permissions are correct? The correct user needs write permission

Comment: @ColinShipton Permissions should be okay (same user and group as the one that runs all lighttpd processes)

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong At least the access log shows that the request for one of the modified pictures comes in, but is answered with a 404.

Comment: url.rewrtie-if-not-file seems not to work, I'm giving up after a goog days work now: `url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
                 "^/(.*)$" => "/index.php?q=$1"
     )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your lighttpd rewrite rule to this :

```
url.rewrite-final = (
"^/system/test/(.*)$" => "/index.php?q=system/test/$1",
"^/([^.?]*)\?(.*)$" => "/index.php?q=$1&$2",
"^/([^.?]*)$" => "/index.php?q=$1",
"^/rss.xml" => "/index.php?q=rss.xml",
"^/(.+/files/styles/.+\.+.+)\?(.*)$" => "/index.php?q=$1&$2"
)
```

That must work. if not disable the clean ulrs to see if the problem is solved or not .

Comment: It worked out of the box this way and I have no side effects so far. I've been afraid I had to hassle with mod_magnet to solve the issue...

Comment: I’m glad I could help.